# Launching phone/email/map links in WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, wkwebview

[KINWebBrowser](https://github.com/dfmuir/KINWebBrowser) is an open source web browser module for iOS apps. I recently upgraded KINWebBrowser to use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html) to begin phasing out UIWebView. This yields significant improvements, but:

Problem: WKWebView does not enable users to launch links containing URLs for phone numbers, email address, maps, etc.

How can I configure a WKWebView to launch the standard iOS behaviors for these alternate URLs when launched as links from the displayed page?

All of the [code is available here](https://github.com/dfmuir/KINWebBrowser)

More info on [WKWebKit](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/)

See the [issue on the KINWebBrowser GitHub here](https://github.com/dfmuir/KINWebBrowser/issues/10)

Comment: You can't do it. If this functionality is important to you, that would be a reason for sticking with UIWebView for now - and for filing an enhancement request with Apple. There are a _lot_ of things UIWebView can do that WKWebView can't do.

Answer (score 27):

I was able to get it to work for the Google Maps link (which appears to be related to the target="_blank") and for the tel: scheme by adding this function to your KINWebBrowserViewController.m

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{
    if(webView != self.wkWebView) {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
        return;
    }

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSURL         *url = navigationAction.request.URL;

    if (!navigationAction.targetFrame) {
        if ([app canOpenURL:url]) {
            [app openURL:url];
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
            return;
        }
    }
    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"])
    {
        if ([app canOpenURL:url])
        {
            [app openURL:url];
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
            return;
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

Comment: This code is a little verbose, and doesn't guarantee `decisionHandler` is called.

Comment: Good point!  Thanks.  This was a late night, last minute patch from 2 different sources thrown together to quickly solve a problem.  While it did work, not the cleanest and there definitely were cases where decisionHandler wasn't being called.  I've edited the code.  Thx!

Comment: This code is definitely on the right path but it introduces a security vulnerability that may allow calls and FaceTime calls to be unwillingly initiated. Check out my explanation here: https://github.com/dfmuir/KINWebBrowser/issues/10

Comment: Excellent catch.  In my case, the app only displays closely controlled webpages (for internal information views), so we're currently safe.  But excellent point all the same!

Comment: This solution has helped us tremendously at my company. Thank you Darren. We were able to modify it slightly to also open up the app store from a link from our web page and open the email app from tapping on a link in our web page as well. Cheers!

Comment: To avoid the security vulnerability issue that @dfmuir pointed out, change the url to "telprompt" instead of the default "tel". For example, if the original custom URL is "tel:(212)%20555-6666" then the telprompt equivalent is "telprompt:(212)%20555-6666". This way the user will get a prompt before making the call

Answer (score 13):

Works on xcode 8.1, Swift 2.3.

For target="_blank", phone number (tel:) and email (mailto:) links.

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if webView != self.webview {
        decisionHandler(.Allow)
        return
    }

    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    if let url = navigationAction.request.URL {
        // Handle target="_blank"
        if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
            if app.canOpenURL(url) {
                app.openURL(url)
                decisionHandler(.Cancel)
                return
            }
        }

        // Handle phone and email links
        if url.scheme == "tel" || url.scheme == "mailto" {
            if app.canOpenURL(url) {
                app.openURL(url)
                decisionHandler(.Cancel)
                return
            }
        }

        decisionHandler(.Allow)
    }
}
```

**Updated for swift 4.0**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    if webView != self.webView {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        return
    }

    let app = UIApplication.shared
    if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
        // Handle target="_blank"
        if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
            if app.canOpenURL(url) {
                app.open(url)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                return
            }
        }

        // Handle phone and email links
        if url.scheme == "tel" || url.scheme == "mailto" {
            if app.canOpenURL(url) {
                app.open(url)
            }

            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }

        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

}
```

Comment: Don´t forget to add delegate: WKUIDelegate and var webView = WKWebView() to properties

Answer (score 9):

You need to implemented an other callback to get this right (Swift 5.0):

```
// Gets called if webView cant handle URL
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
  guard let failingUrlStr = (error as NSError).userInfo["NSErrorFailingURLStringKey"] as? String  else { return }
  let failingUrl = URL(string: failingUrlStr)!

  switch failingUrl {
    // Needed to open Facebook
    case _ where failingUrlStr.hasPrefix("fb:"):
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       UIApplication.shared.open(failingUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
       return
    } // Else: Do nothing, iOS 9 and earlier will handle this

  // Needed to open Mail-app
  case _ where failingUrlStr.hasPrefix("mailto:"):
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(failingUrl) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(failingUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
      return
    }

  // Needed to open Appstore-App
  case _ where failingUrlStr.hasPrefix("itmss://itunes.apple.com/"):
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(failingUrl) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(failingUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
      return
    }

  default: break
  }
}
```

Now Facebook, Mail, Appstore,.. getting called directly from your app without the need to open Safari

Edit: replaced custom startsWith() method with standard hasPrefix() method.

Comment: What is startsWith?

Comment: Its the same as hasPrefix()

Comment: but why tel scheme fails to load?

Answer (score 0):

This helps me for Xcode 8 WKWebview

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
        let url = navigationAction.request.url
        if url?.description.range(of: "http://") != nil || url?.description.range(of: "https://") != nil || url?.description.range(of: "mailto:") != nil || url?.description.range(of: "tel:") != nil  {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

***EDITED:***

In link must be attribute `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm landed here searching for how to open gmail attachments on wkwebview.

My solution is simple:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil, let redirect = navigationAction.request.url {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(redirect) {
            self.webViewMail?.load(navigationAction.request)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT 4.2**

Sorry to dig up an old post, but I was having the same issues and have updated the solution for Swift 4.2. I have put my solution here so that it may help others and if not I will hopefully find it the next time I am working with WKWebView!

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    let url = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString
    let urlElements = url?.components(separatedBy: ":") ?? []

    switch urlElements[0] {

    case "tel":
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    case "mailto":
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    default:
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

I used the following site as inspiration:

[SubzDesignz iOS Swift 4 WKWebview – Detect tel, mailto, target=”_blank” and CheckConnection](https://subzdesigns.com/blog/WKWebView-tel-mailto-target-blank-check-connection)

Answer (score -1):

Above answer workes for me, but I needed it to rewrite for swift 2.3

```
if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
    let url = navigationAction.request.mainDocumentURL
    if url?.description.rangeOfString("mailto:")?.startIndex != nil ||
        url?.description.rangeOfString("tel:")?.startIndex != nil
    {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!,options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)  // deprecated
        }
    }
}
```