# wkwebview mailto and tel not working

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I had mailto and tel working fine until i migrated to wkwebview, i searched through internet and have got some snippets but all of them are dealing with target="_blank" which i don't need and confused on that part.

I am having hard time converting this to swift, just hoping to get something out of it,
[Launching phone/email/map links in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501172/launching-phone-email-map-links-in-wkwebview)